# Dataset format filtering in CKAN

Tags: solr, ckan

In CKAN, it's possible that a dataset may have multiple resources with various file extensions (e.g. CSV, JSON, etc.).

However, by querying Solr from CKAN with request that contains specific format (e.g. `<CKAN_SITE_URL>/dataset/?res_format=CSV`), I get result contains datasets with format except the CSV (say I'm querying with CSV as requested format) ones, but what I'm expecting is, a result contains only datasets with CSV resource(s).

Does anyone know which field in the Solr schema should I adjust in order to solve the aforementioned problem?

Thanks!

Comment: Are you sure? `res_format=CSV` will return the daset that contains the CSV resource e.g https://demo.ckan.org/dataset/?res_format=CSV

Comment: @ZoranPandovski yes, and I think it's because of my solr configuration problem (I'm using solr 7.6). Do you know where inside the solr schema should I adjust in order to solve the problem? Thanks!

Comment: That's strange. Which CKAN version are you using? You can check latest https://github.com/ckan/ckan/blob/master/ckan/config/solr/schema.xml#L133

Comment: @ZoranPandovski CKAN 2.9.2. Mine is the same as the line of the schema you provided. Is it possible that there have other fields which may affect field `res_format`? Thanks!